Stripe webhook signature verification with springboot
I am developing an endpoint to receive webhook events from stripe. Using stripe library  to verify the signature.
Webhook.constructEvent(body, sigHeader, "whsec_....");

It always gives me error "Signature not found", i have debugged and found that expected signature is not same as computed signature. I have ensured my signature key is correct and i think issue is with the request body i am getting in spring boot controller.
I am trying to extract the request body as below. what is the correct way to get raw body in spring controller:
@PostMapping("/event")
public ResponseEntity<String> processStripeEvents(@RequestBody String payload, HttpServletRequest request)

I have also tried using apache IOUtils to read body from request but that also gives same error. I am using Webhook.site to test receiving of events, could that be the issue?

What is the exact error message that you received? I don't find Signature not found error in the source code. Note that webhook secret in local server and the one in the Dashboard are different. You should ensure that webhook secret belongs to the correct environment.

Error code is “No signatures found matching the expected signature for payload". I am testing with webhook created in dashboard so using dashboard’s secret.

Finally below code worked for me. @RequestBody or Apache IOUtils doesn't give the original raw body, it does some transformation due to which signatures were not matching.
@PostMapping("/event")
public ResponseEntity<String> processStripeEvents(HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException {
    logger.info("Received event from stripe ");
    Event event = null;
    String body = request.getReader().lines().collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
    try {
        String sigHeader = request.getHeader("Stripe-Signature");
        event = Webhook.constructEvent(body, sigHeader, "whsec_...");
    }  catch (Exception e) {

        logger.error("Error while verifying stripe event signature", e);
        return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(e.getMessage());
    }

}

You should have done this:
    @PostMapping("/event") 
    public ResponseEntity<String> processStripeEvents(@RequestBody String payload,
     @RequestHeader("Stripe-Signature") String signatureHeader) {
        Event event = null;
        String webHookSecret = <WebHoook_skey>;
        
        try {
           event = WebHook.constructEvent(payload,signatureHeader, webHookSecret);
            
        } catch ( Exception e) {}

}


So, your code only answer differs from Suraj's answer in that it takes two string parameters rather than an HttpServletRequest and from the method signature in his question in that his original method took only one string. The question could benefit from more details as to how it is intended to contrast with the existing answer and what methods are used to address the question.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
